# Can I stop upcoming calendar events appearing on windows phone 7 lock screen?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to be able to programmatically customize what notifications appear on the lock screen.

Specifically I'm trying to stop the display of upcoming calendar notifications on the lock screen. I only want to see these when I go into calendar itself.

I have a windows phone developer account so happy to create my own custom app that provides this functionality.

Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of customization is not available in the Windows Phone API.

Comment: ok thanks for response, will this still be the case after mango update do you know?

Comment: I don't know if Mango will allow that type of customization.